# How can I export the chatter attachments from one SF org and upload into another SF org?

Tags: attachment

We are trying to export all the feed attachments (files) and we tried different ways to do it, but none of them were successful.

We tried using the SF Data exporter and the files (attachments) are exported as binary files.

Is there a way to convert them into valid files or while doing the import of these files using data loaders? Is there an option where data loader convert it and upload into SF in the right format?

We are trying to export the chatter attachments from one SF  org and upload into another SF org.

Can anyone please  suggest a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just did something like that for a customer, so I think you can do it...though it depends what the Chatter target is (Files vs Feeds etc)

I used the regular Data Export function - just make sure you check the box for Content, Chatter Files etc, not just attachments - and in the zip file, you should get a content version folder.

If you export the Opportunity Feed object,  as an example, you'll see references to ContentPost, ContentData, and the RELATEDRECORDID. That RelatedRecordId is the content id of the file you'll see in the ContentVersion folder.

So if you migrating Opportunities and their feeds, you can take the OptyFeed file, match up the old OpportunityIds with the new ones you created in the target org, and then set the ContentData column = the full filepath including the relatedrecordid that matches the file in ContentVersion. When you load into the Feed Object, it will create a file and match it the Opportunity Record...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [Skysync](http://skysync.com) can export from Chatter files on Salesforce, and I imagine it can also import as it's a two-way system.  Skysync is a commercial tool, and there's a free trial so you can see if it works for you.